# Elementor\Scheme_Typography' not found

Tags: plugins, updates, fatal-error

I just update my elementor plugin and suddenly my site goes down its display this error.

code line error shows: 224.

```
$element->add_group_control(
            Group_Control_Typography::get_type(),
            [
                'name' => 'eael_tooltip_section_typography',
                'selector' => '.tippy-popper[data-tippy-popper-id="{{ID}}"] .tippy-tooltip',
                 'scheme' => Scheme_Typography::TYPOGRAPHY_3,
                'separator' => 'after',
                'condition' => [
                    'eael_tooltip_section_enable!' => '',
                ],
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Scheme_Typography is deprecated. Use \Elementor\Core\Schemes\Typography instead
https://forum.elementor.com/development-24/deprecated-elementor-scheme-typography-solved-sure-9919